# How to wrap lines in a bulleted list correctly

Tags: formatting, lists

[image: Left pic is what I have, right pic is what I want]

I am new to all this. I am sure there is a solution.

Comment: So you want the pattern on the left image not the right image?

Comment: I want the right, not left.

Comment: The one on the right is the default. So you need to show code for how you made the list.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

This will also serve as a test case and ensure that the solution actually works for you.

Comment: Amusingly, I'm trying to achieve the behavior on the left—and this question pops up in the search results. Pity the user didn't show how they achieved it.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, this is the default setup that the text is wrapped and indented and not aligned under the bullet:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Foo
\item \blindtext
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]